# ng-click won't work with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have html template like this:

```
$scope.template = '<span class="pointer"><i class="icon-refresh pointer" ng-click="refresh()"></i></span>';
```

I want to bind this template using `ng-bind-html`, I tried to use it and also I used `ng-bind-html-unsafe`, but unfortunately It bind the html string as it is with no click action.

```
<span ng-bind-html="template"></span>
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="template"></span>
```

I read about similar problem and it said that `ng-click` is loaded after `ng-bind`, so can anybody introduce to me how to solve this problem?

Comment: The fact Angular makes it so difficult to do this highlights exactly *why* you shouldn't do it. HTML does not belong in the Controller. Pull it in via the View

Comment: Why do you need to have a template in a JS variable ?

Comment: In the project I'm working on I have to bind templates to sub-views in the main view, so I need to bin the template in the required panel (sub-view) with its functions

Comment: What version of Angular are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ng-include and put your template in to a static file instead.

Putting HTML content in scope variables kind of goes against some angular philosophy guidelines, I believe.

If you were to later change the template, would you want it to rebind itself and be processed again?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to compile the template inside the controller?

```
angular.controller('ABCDCtrl', function($scope, $compile){
    var templateHTML = '<span class="pointer"><i class="icon-refresh pointer" ng-click="refresh()"></i></span>';
    $scope.template = $compile(templateHTML)($scope);
});
```